# Passing main parameter to sub-datasets in JasperStudio

Tags: jasper-reports, report

i'm created a report with JasperStudio 5.5 that have many parameter defined in the main and a lot of sub-dataset (defined with tables) that required this parameters.

The situation:

/main/Parameters: myPar

/main/mySubDataSet1/
/main/mySubDataSet2/
...
/main/mySubDataSetN/

The sub-dataset need to use this parameter in her query: select * from Tab t where t.attr = $P!{myPar}

So, my problem is that the sub-dataset can't access at this main paramenter, all the time that i try compiled, the program send me "Parameter not found : myPar".

How i can do for use myPar in the sub-dataset?

p.s.: i read this thread [Pass main dataset parameter to subdataset query](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541915/pass-main-dataset-parameter-subdataset-query) (based on iReport) but without success...

Comment: Another user send me the method: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/823038/passing-main-parameter-sub-datasets-jasperstudio#comment-805329

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you need to fill subDataset parameters with values where you actually make use of them. In this case the table which lists items from your subDataset needs to declare the necessary parameters and assign the values of the report-level dataset parameters to them.

In jrxml it sounds:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
    <datasetRun subDataset="mySubDataSet1" uuid="bbe7937c-a8f1-4838-811a-3f11ec1f8e35">
        <datasetParameter name="myPar">
            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{myPar}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
        </datasetParameter>
        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    ...
</jr:table>
```

Comment: Thanks alots... it's really very helpful

Answer (score 2):

For detail:

```
<subDataset name="dsLines" uuid="a47307ff-90a8-476f-afd1-0fd8aa0517d0">
<parameter name="formalId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT s.formalid, sl.*
        FROM salesorder s INNER JOIN salesorderline sl
        ON (s.id = sl.salesorder_id)
        WHERE s.formalid = $P{formalId}
    ]]>
</queryString>
<field name="qty" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
...
```

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
<datasetRun subDataset="dsLines" uuid="3ef5ec78-ab18-4f44-88e6-f99f3eafac07">
<datasetParameter name="formalId">
    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{formalid}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
</datasetParameter>
</datasetRun>
<jr:column width="29" uuid="f675a273-7ea6-4bd4-8a55-c7522dfea2a8">
    ...
```

Comment: My mistake was to try assigning a default value in the subdataset declaration with the value of parent report parameter. This would just void the value. Instead, use above solution would make it work. Thanks !