# Why am I unable to sum up javabean subitem's value in jrtable?

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans

I get this exception when tying to sum nested column values

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
 1. Field not found : episodeCount
 2. Variable not found : episodeTotal
```

How would I pass the above parameter/variable(s) to the sub dataset?

**My jrxml file**

```
<subDataset name="dataset1">
    <field name="orderItem" class="com.blahblah.OrderItemPDF">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>

<field name="orderItems" class="java.util.Collection"/>
<field name="episodeCount" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$F{orderItem}.getEpisodeCount()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

<variable name="episodeTotal" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{episodeCount}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>

<title>
    <band height="113" splitType="Stretch">

    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="360">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="67" y="181" width="360" height="100"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
                    <dataSourceExpression>
                        <![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{orderItems})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="130">
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Media Families]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression>
                                <![CDATA[$F{orderItem}.getMediaFamilyName()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="130">
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <text><![CDATA[Episodes]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderItem}.getEpisodeCount()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="60">
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[AdUnits]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <!--<jr:columnFooter height="20">-->
                        <!--<textField>-->
                            <!--<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20"/>-->
                            <!--<textElement/>-->
                            <!--<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{episodeTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>-->
                        <!--</textField>-->
                    <!--</jr:columnFooter>-->
                    <jr:detailCell height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderItem}.getAdUnitCount()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>jas
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band/>
</detail>
```

Comment: Your are missing to tell us how $F{payment} is defined? and to show us the java code of this code public ? getPayment(), related since you indicate: Error retrieving field value from bean : $F{subItem}.getPayment()

Comment: Instead of splitting up the jrxml it would be nice with a complete simplified jrxml (the variable must be defined within the scope of the subdataset), hence I can not understand where you have this variable definition

Comment: Okay i will amend now using the actual scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `subDataset` you need to define all your fields, parameter and variables  **inside** of the `subDataset`. You can **not** reference fields, parameters and variables that are outside.

In **your example** the definition of the variable **inside** the `subDataset` would be something like this

```
<subDataset name="dataset1">
    <field name="orderItem" class="com.blahblah.OrderItemPDF">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="episodeTotal" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderItem}.getEpisodeCount()]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
</subDataset>
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. This was solution i needed.

Answer (score 1):

The variables and parameters and resources that are defined in outside of jrxml cannot be access from Data Set or Table directly. You need to explicitly pass these as parameter to the dataset. Otherwise, it is getting Not found error.

Something similar to 
[Passing main parameter to sub-datasets in JasperStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241303/passing-main-parameter-to-sub-datasets-in-jasperstudio)

Comment: Hi @Kyaw based on my current example could you show me where and how i passed them?

Comment: Your first line is perfectly correct, but in this example it is more a problem of where to define the variable and not an issue of passing parameters.